# How long can a domain controller not be in contact with the domain without causing problems?

Tags: domain-controller, windows-server-2012-r2

Server 2012 R2 w/ GUI in Hyper-V role, hosting VM servers.  Very small system at present.

Primary Servers in this system are: Domain Controller(DC), SQL, TFS, IIS, Build server

I successfully installed my second DC on a new physical Hyper-V host.  I was able to see the Enable Recycle change made on the new DC reflected on the old DC, so I presume everything is going well.  I also intend to shift the PDCe functions to this new DC on the physical server.

At present I have just the one physical server that hosts (or will host) most of my servers as listed above.  Prior to getting this machine, I had successfully hosted all of my servers in a Win 8.1 workstation (It's a pretty big workstation).  Until I get another machine, my temporary plan was to keep the old DC operating as a vm Server running on the Win 8.1 workstation that is still acting as a Hyper-V host.  In that manner I have 2 DC's, each on a different machine.  But the workstation hosting the original DC won't be on 24/7, so that DC will be 'off the domain' for temporary periods.

**So my questions are**, how long can my DC server hosted on the workstation be 'off the domain' before I would experience problems, and what would those problems be?

Of course, if anyone thinks this is a really terrible solution, feel free to advise what problems I might expect.  But if it is a reasonable temporary solution until I am able to procure another physical machine, then I'd like to stay with it.

Comment: Maybe this could answer your question : http://serverfault.com/questions/579231/whats-the-downtime-limit-of-a-domain-controller-dc

Comment: I didn't see that question in my search, thanks!  So technically, unless I change it, 180 days is the limit.  I would never even approach that limit b/c I work on the system M-F, so effectively the 2nd DC on the workstation will be on the domain pretty regularly.  While you answered my main question, what problems do we experience if a DC is off the domain past the limit?

Comment: Past the limit, no way to authenticate clients/services against AD. From there, you are the only one able to measure the impact regarding how you use AD services within your network.

Comment: So do you just kill that DC permanently and create another one?  They're not that hard to spin up, right?